# Arduino-cli commands are not found in vscode using WSL, why is this occuring?

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, arduino-cli

It appears that people have had similar issues using vscode locally, however, I am trying to configure things purely on the WSL side.

I installed the Arduino extension using vscode, however, none of the arduino commands are able to be found in the vscode terminal. (ie. arduino.verify, arduino.selectSerialPort, etc.)

I then went on to decide that I would just manually install the arduino-cli in wsl, add it to my path, then set the path in vscode.

```
    "arduino.useArduinoCli": true,
    "arduino.path": "/home/pathtobin/bin", // directory containing arduino-cli binary
    "arduino.commandPath": "arduino-cli"
```

However, none of this seems to work on the vscode side of things. If I open the wsl terminal in vscode and run `arduino-cli version` then I can see that the binary is present and seems to be working. I double checked permissions and everything is fine in that regard as well.
`arduino-cli  Version: 0.35.3 Commit: 95cfd654 Date: 2024-02-19T13:24:24Z`

Am I overlooking something obvious here? Could this be a vscode issue?

I have verified that all of the paths are correct, the extension is installed in vscode, arduino-cli is present and working, and reread the documentation and common issues plenty of times.